# How to handle click event on table at first column using jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
 $('tr').click(function() {
        $("#showgrid").load('/Products/List/Items/');
    });
```

Using this I am handling click event on the row of the table.

How can I handle only on the first column? that is, giving click action to only first column not on entire row?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle the first column using [`:first-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/), like this:

```
$('tr td:first-child').click(function() {
  $("#showgrid").load('/Products/List/Items/');
});
```

This selector returns the first `<td>` in each `<tr>`.

Alternatively, if you have a lot of rows, use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for better performance (only one event handler), like this:

```
$('#myTable').delegate('tr td:first-child', 'click', function() {
  $('#showgrid').load('/Products/List/Items/');
});
```

Comment: @Hunter - I've explicitly specified `td` in the selector, it'll select each `td` that is *also* a first-child of it's parent.

Comment: I need to get the first-child value? with that that click?

Answer (score 1):

that is simple. just add an event handler to the first td of each tr of the table.
this jQuery code is almost like speaking it.

```
$("#table tr").find("td:first").click(function() { 
    $("#showgrid").load('/Products/List/Items/');
});
```